# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

My problem is when i try to run this code

```
if log_to_tensorboard: from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
if log_to_tensorboard: writer = SummaryWriter()
```

I get this error:

(import SummaryWriter works without any problems, but then I try run "writer = SummaryWriter()" and it doesnt work)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d77d9d09e62b> in <module>
----> 1 writer = SummaryWriter()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py in __init__(self, log_dir, comment, purge_step, max_queue, flush_secs, filename_suffix)
    223         # and recreated later as needed.
    224         self.file_writer = self.all_writers = None
--> 225         self._get_file_writer()
    226 
    227         # Create default bins for histograms, see generate_testdata.py in tensorflow/tensorboard

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py in _get_file_writer(self)
    254         if self.all_writers is None or self.file_writer is None:
    255             self.file_writer = FileWriter(self.log_dir, self.max_queue,
--> 256                                           self.flush_secs, self.filename_suffix)
    257             self.all_writers = {self.file_writer.get_logdir(): self.file_writer}
    258             if self.purge_step is not None:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py in __init__(self, log_dir, max_queue, flush_secs, filename_suffix)
     64         log_dir = str(log_dir)
     65         self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(
---> 66             log_dir, max_queue, flush_secs, filename_suffix)
     67 
     68     def get_logdir(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py in __init__(self, logdir, max_queue_size, flush_secs, filename_suffix)
     71         """
     72         self._logdir = logdir
---> 73         if not tf.io.gfile.exists(logdir):
     74             tf.io.gfile.makedirs(logdir)
     75         self._file_name = os.path.join(logdir, "events.out.tfevents.%010d.%s.%s.%s" %

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/lazy.py in __getattr__(self, attr_name)
     63     class LazyModule(types.ModuleType):
     64       def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
---> 65         return getattr(load_once(self), attr_name)
     66 
     67       def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io'
```

How to fix it?
I uninstall and install tensorflow, upgraded tensorboard and torch - that didnt help me

Comment: what is your TF version?

Comment: now version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. And my solution is as follow:

1. Check to see if `tensorflow-tensorboard` is exists.

```
 pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard
```

2. install tensorboard==1.14

because an error occurred: TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard with Python summary writer installed. This should be available in 1.14 or above.

ref: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20140

```
pip install tensorboard==1.14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by using the solution recommended [here](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_41194171/article/details/111225093) which suggests to:

```sh
pip install tensorflow-io
```

Comment: solved my problem on a linux machine

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error after upgrading my pytorch and tensorboard versions. None of the proposal here worked for me. I upgraded tensorflow to the latest version installed other tensorflow-* packages suggested by others. Nothing worked. Eventually I found forcing tensorflow_stub to load is the solution as in  [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/c7422700fd8c768146f855a6545b2dc1127c558f/tensorboard/compat/__init__.py#L41-L52). So the simple solution for me is to uninstall tensorflow (and the other tensorflow-*) versions. In other words

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

For good measure I also rebooted the machine after uninstalling and the error went away

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard) and change

```
from tensorboard.compat import tf
```

to

```
from tensorboard.compat.tensorflow_stub import io
```

Answer (score -3):

You can upgrade the version of tensorboard

Comment: The OP mentioned it is upgraded to 1.71. Please be specific to which version would solve the problem.